# animate MovieClip using addEventListener - actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, arguments, flash-cs5, addeventlistener

actually i can finish this code, but i'm misunderstanding with arguments and removeEventListener. I have two codes that have the same goal, this is my first code :

First Code :

```js
    public function walk(){
        var bob:bob= new bob();
        bob.x = 0;
        bob.y = 300;
        addChild(bob);
        bobRun();
    }
    private function bobRun(){
        bob.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateBob);
    }
    private function animateBob(event:Event) {
        if (bob.x <= 200){
            bob.x += 2;
            bob.gotoAndPlay(bob.currentFrame);
        } else { 
            bob.gotoAndStop(1);
            trace("bob.stop");
            bob.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateBob);
        }
    }
```

Second code :

```js
    public function walk(){
        var choose:boolean = false;
        bobRun(0, 300, 200, 300);
    } 
    private function bobRun(startX:Number, startY:Number, endX:Number, endY:Number){
        bob.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void{
        startX = bob.x; startY = bob.y; 
        if (startX != endX || startY != endY){
            choose = true;
            if (startX < endX && startY > endY){
                bob.x += 1;
                bob.y -= 1;
            } if (startX > endX && startY < endY){
                bob.x -= 1;
                bob.y += 1;
            } if (startX == endX && startY > endY){
                bob.y -= 1;
            } if (startX == endX && startY < endY){
                bob.y += 1;
            } if (startX < endX && startY == endY){
                bob.x += 1;
            } if (startX > endX && startY == endY){
                bob.x -= 1;
            }
            bob.gotoAndPlay(bob.currentFrame);
        } else {
            bob.gotoAndStop(1);
            trace("bob.stop");
        }
        })
    }
```

in first code, i'm using **bob.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateBob);** to remove the listener, and thats work fine, but in first code i can't using arguments like second code **bobRun(startX:Number, startY:Number, endX:Number, endY:Number)**.

in second code i can't remove the listener like the first code **bob.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateBob);**, so **trace("bob.stop");** can't stop in output panel, but i can use the arguments.

I needs the arguments and removeEventListener to build my project, so please help me guys. :'(

Comment: this problem is closed, i found the solution. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first snippet of code, you could just use an intermediary function if you want to pass arguments.

e.g.

```
private function bobRun(){
    bob.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameEventHandler);
}

public function enterFrameEventHandler(e:Event):void{
    animateBob(arg1,arg2,arg3); //this is where you would pass your arguments
}
```

For the second snippet of code you are using an anonymous function; thus, you could simply add...

```
e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
```

...in whatever portion of the logic you feel like removing the listener.